# How to convert json type data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

```
{'data': 'key=IAfpK, age=58, key=WNVdi, age=64, key=jp9zt, age=47, 
 key=0Sr4C, age=68, key=CGEqo, age=76, key=IxKVQ, age=79, key=eD221, age=29,
 key=XZbHV, age=32, key=k1SN5, age=88, key=4SCsU, age=65, key=q3kG6, age=33,
 key=MGQpf, age=13, key=Kj6xW, age=14, key=tg2VM, age=30, key=WSnCU, age=24,
 key=f1Vvz, age=46, key=dOS7A, age=72, key=tDojg, age=82, key=nZyJA, age=48,
 key=R8JTk, age=29, key=005Ot, age=66, key=HHROm, age=12, key=5yzG8, age=51,
 key=xMJ5D, age=38, key=TXtVu, age=82, key=Hz38B, age=84}
```

i need to get the key values who age > 50
i could do this by converting this to dictionary and split value by comma separated and apply the condition
But i want to use pandas dataframe for this .  Can any one please help ?

Comment: The sample data you have shared needs pre-processing. Is this how you get the entire dataset? If not, please share the exact format of your source data.

Comment: Unfortunately, most Python tools processing json data would convert this to a dictionary and will leave you with one single key, age pair. So you will have to first parse it *by hand* into a list of pairs or dictionaries key, age. That list could then easily initialize a dataframe.

Comment: Your JSON sample contains *'data'* (so far OK, the string is enclosed
between apostrophes). But where is closing apostrophe paired with the
one preceding the first *key*?
I also suppose that each *key* / *age* pair should be surrounded with
brackets.
If you ask a question then include **properly** formatted JSON sample.